# Inline LI with Spans

Tags: html, css

I have a button called Delete next to a link inside a DIV per list item. To confirm I have another button that should appear next to called Confirm Delete. When that is clicked it is posted back to server. The Delete appears correctly but the confirm drops down to the next line instead of appearing on the same line.

Source:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="font-size: x-large;">
            <a href="/item/detail/123>Rearden Steel</a> 
        </div>

        <button type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="ShowDeleteButton('Delete123', this);" class="btn btn-default btn-primary disableOnClickSubmit">Delete</button>

        <span id="Delete123" style="display: none;">
            <form action="/item/ItemDelete" method="post">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="123" />                            
                <button type="submit" name="deleteConfirm" value="DeleteConfirm" class="btn btn-default disableOnClickSubmit">Confirm Delete</button>
            </form>                
        </span>
    </li>
    <li> ... </li>
<ul>
```

What style do I need to apply to have the confirm Delete button appear on the same line as the link and Delete button?

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Bootply Example: http://www.bootply.com/VsU984gbLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do either of these to make `<li>` come in the same line.

- `display: inline-block`: You should ensure you have no space character between `<li>`s.
- `float: left`: You should ensure to clear the floats.

Remember the caveats above. Since you are using Bootstrap, you may use the utility class: `pull-left` or `pull-right`. The best thing is to make sure the pattern you want is already present in the framework and use the mark-up instead of creating your own styles.

Comment: This is typical for people who use Bootstrap instead of properly learning the underlying core technology CSS. They fail to modify even very basic stuff.

Comment: @connexo I agree on this with you mate. Kindly refresh and see the note I have added at the bottom. Is there anything that I can make to make this answer better and stand out?

Comment: That was no criticism on you, but on people jumping on Bootstrap or Foundation or whatever while still having no clue about what that's built upon.

Comment: @connexo I am smart enough you are just telling me something. Don't worry mate. I am just asking you, how's my answer and if there's anything that I can make to improve. `:)` Just second thoughts.

Comment: "display: inline-block" doesn't have an effect. Adding "display: inline-block, float: left" causes the LI below to be pulled up like a second column of data.

Comment: @Josh Do you want to show me a snippet, fiddle, or a bootply to exactly demonstrate what you are seeing?

Comment: @Josh You want something like this: http://www.bootply.com/tY4Cz2lxh5 Added borders to show that `<li>`s are aligning correctly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, the content isn't on the same line

Comment: @Josh Come to chat.